# Custom order sorting in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have a column as color which having data as

```
"red","blue","white","black","yellow"
```

Now I want to sort them like

```
"yellow","blue","red","white" and "black"
```

It means I don't need sorting in alphabetical order.

I want it to customized.

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5hb9spz/2/)

just like you do in mysql:
ORDER BY FIELD(color,'yellow','blue','red',"white","black")

Comment: on what basis ? any particular algorithm or custom algorithm for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you can implement sorting function like this:

```
var colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'white', 'black'];

$scope.customOrder = function(friend) {
    return colors.indexOf(friend.color);
};
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/f5hb9spz/3/